# Elasticsearch multi search API

Tags: elasticsearch, concurrency

I'm trying to perform multiple concurrent search requests using Elasticsearch (version 6). Here is my queries file:

```
{"index" : "web"}
{"max_concurrent_searches": 64, "query": {"match": {"content": "school"}}}
{"index" : "web"}
{"max_concurrent_searches": 64, "query": {"match": {"content": "car"}}}
{"index" : "web"}
{"max_concurrent_searches": 64, "query": {"match": {"content": "cat"}}}
```

Here is the command I use to issue the bulk request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XGET ''$url'/_msearch'
--data-binary "@$file"; echo
```

However, I get the following error indicating my wrong usage of `max_concurrent_searches` parameter.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a VALUE_NUMBER in [max_concurrent_searches].","line":1,"col":29}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a VALUE_NUMBER in [max_concurrent_searches].","line":1,"col":29},"status":400}
```

If I removed `"max_concurrent_searches": 64,` from the queries file above, everything works just perfect.

I want to know how can I use/set the `max_concurrent_searches` parameter, I couldn't find useful information in [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-multi-search.html) about this except the following:

> The msearch’s max_concurrent_searches request parameter can be used to
>   control the maximum number of concurrent searches the multi search api
>   will execute. This default is based on the number of data nodes and
>   the default search thread pool size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it to the request itself:

Sample request: GET indexName/type/_msearch?**max_concurrent_searches=1100**
(where indexName and type is optional)

For you its should be like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XGET ''$url'/_msearch**? 
max_concurrent_searches=1100**'
--data-binary "@$file"; echo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute above using postman also. Just change the content-type as `application/x-ndjson` and dont forget to add a new line character in the end. This will give you the same error and you can correct it easily by different combinations. MultiSearch is an important feature.